# New to R and PHP tried redirecting a form data to R script

Tags: php, html, r, post, machine-learning

I have a form which i am using for a survey and what i want to do is whenever the user will fill the form the data so collected should be passed to the R scrip as a CSV i have tried a lot of solutions but didn't work out

I have tired using the exec() command and shell_exec() also

```
form action="scr.php" method="GET">

<h2>please select the option below</h2>
<hr>
<h2>In the past 20 days how often have you have</h2>

<h2>Little interest or pleasure in doing things</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="Pleasure" value=" Not at all"> Not at all<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Pleasure" value="Sometimes">Sometimes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Pleasure" value="Several days">Several days<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Pleasure" value="More than half the days">More than half the days<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Pleasure" value="Nearly everyday">Nearly everyday<br>
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>
```

```php
#src.php file
<?php
$files= glob('output/*');
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file);

}
 $Pleasure=$_GET['Pleasure'];
$output=shell_exec("Rscript //C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1\\bin\\Rscript.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\final\\predscript.R $Pleasure");
    echo $output;
    echo"<img src='output/output.png'>";
    $files=scandir('./output');
    sort($files);
    foreach($files as $file)

        echo'<a href="output/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
         echo '<br>';
?>
```

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library('Metrics')
library(e1071)

df_main <- read.csv("entries.csv", sep = ',', header = TRUE)
```

What i was expecting was the form should redirected the user inputs as csv to the R scrip and R script gets executed